# bottom div not centered

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the bottom section of my layout doesn't seem to be centered when I have set the left and right margin to auto

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kvtcp

Please see the example.

I have since changed the code with some example you have provide but I have another issue. The bottom div has pushed up to left and right section div?

I have used margin-top 20px and nothing happens

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is occuring because you have the div set to float left and the screen is the left edge.
Your divs above have margin left to pad them in.

I would suggest center your container.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sHvCA

```
body{  
    background:#90F;
}
#container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1200px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    overflow: auto;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.header {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
}
.leftimage {
    float: left;
}
.middle {
    height: 200px;
    background:#FFF;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.leftsection {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.rightsection {
    background-color: #0F0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 479px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bottomsection {
  clear:both;
    height: 200px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

</style>
```

Comment: I have changed the code but when I do my bottom div pushed right up to the left and right section div.  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kvtcp

Comment: Margin- top can be a little flakey. Use margin bottom on divs above.
.leftsection {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

Comment: Hi DreamTek I have and nothing happens? Any ideas?

Comment: looks ok on your link?

Comment: I used the code you gave me and worked fine, but when I was typing in myself I my have missed something

Answer (score 3):

Just remove:

```
float:left
```

from the .bottomsection class
and add

```
clear:both;
```

instead...

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have `float:left;` on it.  Remove that, and add `clear:both;` instead.

I would recommend wrapping the left and right floated divs in another div, and apply `overflow:hidden` on the outer div for better control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
remove the float from your bottom div.

```
.bottomsection {
    height: 200px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 800px;
    /*float: left;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

And in your HTML you have to clear the floats with i.e

```
<div class="leftsection"></div> 
<div class="rightsection"></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="bottomsection"></div>
```

This is a quick and dirty solution.

Here is a good link i.e. about floating div´s

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: worked like a charm. This floating it's the hardest part for me to get used to :(. Thank you to everyone that has posted to assist me. God bless

Answer (score 0):

It is floating for no reason and this causes showing up on the left side. Remove that. This time it should be fine, but you won't be able to see it because it has nothing in it. Add `overflow:hidden;` to avoid this. Then you might want to give some margin as well. And please keep in mind, use floats wise, not every problem requires float.